# How to migrate slate json text to tiptap based prosemirror format? Are there any converters/bindings for this?

Tags: javascript, text-editor, tiptap, slatejs, prose-mirror

I have a text editor that is based on slate js and yjs websocket stack for collaboration editing.
For sometime now slate has proven to be unreliable prompting our migration to tiptap.
Now tiptap is based on prosemirror format which is different than slate json.
I need to migrate my old text editor files in db from slate json to prosemirror to ensure it is backward compatible.
How can I implement this? Are there any online converters available.
reference guides -
https://github.com/ueberdosis/tiptap
https://github.com/ianstormtaylor/slate

I tried using an already available slate json to html converter and then convert HTML to prosemirror json.
But there is always some data left out in conversion.

Comment: Have you tried loading the slate state into a Yjs doc, saving the Yjs doc, and then loading it into a Yjs doc bound to tiptap? They both use Y.XmlFragment internally, though possibly in incompatible ways.